# attribute "for" apply to other tags than label

Tags: html

Why when i put the attribute `for` in other tags than `<label>` it doesn't work (the checkbox didn't get check)

HTML : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4kSsN/1/)

```
<input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox"  />
<div class="item_acc" for="ac-1">   
    <span>CC</span>
    <label>Hello</label>                        
</div>
```

and this works with label of course

HTML : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4kSsN/)

```
<input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox"  />
<div class="item_acc" for="ac-1">   
    <span>CC</span>
    <label>Hello</label>                        
</div>
```

UPDATE :
I fix this problem by adding the pseudo class :before and i put into it what i want to be next my label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` attribute is not one of the [global HTML attributes which can apply to any element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes), it is [specifically defined on the `<label>` element itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

Therefore, there is no reason to expect it to work on another element such as a `<div>`.

Comment: @Youssef Another alternative for what? You haven't specified what problem you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: alternative for check the checkbox after clicking on a div with no javascript.

Comment: @Youssef I'm not aware of anything, just as you can't make a block into a link just by adding an href attribute to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative for your question you misplaced the order ... Why don't you alter the order of your html element like this ...? there is no for attribute for div tag...

```
<label for="ac-1" >Hello</label>
<input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox"  /> 
<div class="item_acc">  
    <span>CC</span>                     
</div>
```